# Op-Amp based power supply, what powers the Op-Amps?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I have seen some schematics of power supplies. They contain Op-Amps inside to implement negative feedback. I was wondering, hmmmm what powers the Op-Amps so they can actually work and implement negative feedback? Unlike diodes and transistors, the Op-Amps need power supply and that also would have to be a stable one. So how are Op-Amps inside a power supply powered up?

Comment: Post an example and we'll look at that. Or you can just look at where the opamp power pins are connected. Usually it's just across the input.

Comment: The answer varies depending on the type of power supply and its input voltage.  In some off-line power supplies, the auxiliary power arrangement can be fairly elaborate.

Comment: I saw the schematic at work, I saw an example somewhere else but can't remember where. It is time to sleep now but I will try to find it.

Answer (score 3):

"Op-Amps need power supply and that also would have to be a stable one." Not really. The typical/cheap linear regulator (e.g. LM317) conceptually looks like the diagram below (taken from Clayton and Winder's *Operational Amplifiers* so it's somewhat authoritative.) The error-magnifying opamp (inside) is simply powered by the unregulated supply/input. The output of this opamp will be affected by variations in its (unregulated) supply in proportion to its PSRR. Nevertheless the output regulation it provides is quite good.

[image]

You can find actual LM317 circuits (down to transistor level) on the net, but don't ask me to analyse those here.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. They're powered by the voltages they control themselves or by the unregulated input (or sometimes a combination of the two).

In the case where they're powered only by the voltage they control themselves, there must be provision given to allow the circuit to start before the op-amp is guaranteed to be functional. For example, for a linear regulator you might have a resistor to allow the output to source current, and the op-amp would throttle the pass transistor back as it comes alive.

Edit: As Nick Alexeev mentioned in his comment, sometimes there is an entire auxiliary supply (switching or otherwise) to power the control circuitry. This is especially likely in very high power switching power supplies.

Comment: WOW! they actually power themselves!? Hmmm. I did expect that to be the only answer but I doubted it.

Comment: I didn't quite say they power themselves. I said they are powered by the voltage they *control* (usually through one or more discrete devices for a linear supply).

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant to say. They are controlling a voltage which is then used to power them up. OK, but I was wondering, if they are not powered upto begin with, how will they generate this controlled voltage to start with? It is more like a chicken and egg situation and that is why I am confused about it.

Comment: No, it's not chicken and egg. A linear power supply will have an input section, usually a transformer, diode bridge and capacitor, which provides "raw" DC to the regulator. This is a higher voltage than the desired output, and will have (depending on current drain) more or less ripple. This raw DC (Vin in your schematic) is what powers the op amp. No mystery there. That said, turn-on behavior can be a problem, with odd glitches and such, and this does require some thought. Mostly, however, the raw DC does not get too high before the op amp becomes effective and the output stabilizes.

Comment: To clarify my previous, the schematic I refer to is in Respawned Fluff's answer.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast A bit of the chicken and egg- the circuit shown does not show the details of the current source. If the majority of the zener current is bootstrapped from the output voltage (could just be a resistor) you can get considerably better line regulation performance from a simple circuit.

Comment: OK guys, I am going to study the schematics again. This information is quite helpful. So I guess it is not possible to have a power supply which does not overshoot immediately at power up, since it will take some time for it to stabilize.

Answer (score 1):

Op-amps have a good Power Supply Rejection ratio (PSRR). I looked up some common op-amps and for a LM324 op-amp you get between 65dB to 100dB and for a LM741 Op-amp it is between 86dB and 96dB.

What this means is that if there is a 1V ripple on the power supply, the output would have in the region of a few micro-volts error ripple on the output for an op-amp with a minimum figure of 65dB. For op-amps with a higher PSRR this would give better results. This PSRR figure is achieved largely due to the very stable current sources in the op-amp.

Answer (score 0):

To power up the op-amp by the stable output voltage controlled by the very op-amp is a clever trick that resembles the *bootstrapping* in the process of starting up a computer... and as I can see, quantum231 is impressed exactly by this idea...

But here the main problem is not from where to power up the op-amp... but sooner the network producing the reference voltage... especially in the simplest case (a resistor and Zener diode in series). So, in this "bootstrapped stabilizer", this network should be supplied by the output voltage as well.